# Updating Multi Select Picklist Using Tooling API - Salesforce

Tags: api, salesforce

I am using Tooling API to update picklist Value. It is giving following Errors :

> Cannot change field type of a custom field referenced in Apex class or
>   trigger:

**Code :**

```
        String json = '{ "Metadata" : { "externalId" : false, "label" : "Meeting Type", "picklist" : { "controllingField" : null, "picklistValues" : [';
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Scope_Of_Services_Tasks__c.Meeting_Type__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry>listpickVal = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        /*Set<string>setPickValue = new set<string>{'Open Items Review','Implementation','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Benefits Review','Vendor Partner Review'};
        for(string plEntry : setPickValue){
            json = json+'{"default" : false, "description" : null, "fullName" : "'+plEntry+'"},';
        }*/

            for(Schema.PicklistEntry plEntry : listpickVal){
                json = json+'{"default" : false, "description" : null, "fullName" : "'+plEntry.getLabel()+'"},';
            }

        json = json+'{"default" : false, "description" : null, "fullName" : "'+picklistval+'"}],"restrictedPicklist" : null,"sorted" : false},"type" : "Picklist","unique" : null,"urls" : null,"visibleLines" : null,"writeRequiresMasterRead" : null },"FullName" : "Scope_Of_Services_Tasks__c.Meeting_Type__c"}';

        System.debug('@@@___'+json);
        Httprequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://cs7.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/tooling/sobjects/customField/00NE0000004t18P?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        req.setBody(json);

        Http httpReq = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
```

Comment: When i remove the reference of the field from Vf Page, It adds value to picklist field using Tooling API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so at this stage, while I'm not 100% sure, this does not seem possible, at least with the **Tooling API**, i've explained a bit more below on what i've tried. In the meantime i can 100% confirm that this does indeed work with the [Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) perfectly! Here is an example...

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();             

    // Read Custom Field
    MetadataService.CustomField customField = 
        (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField', 
            new String[] { 'Lead.picklist__c' }).getRecords()[0];       

    // Add pick list values
    metadataservice.PicklistValue two = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    two.fullName= 'second';
    two.default_x=false;
    metadataservice.PicklistValue three = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    three.fullName= 'third';
    three.default_x=false;
    customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(two);
    customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(three);     

    // Update Custom Field
    handleSaveResults(
        service.updateMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField })[0]);
```

**Theory Regarding Tooling API Error**. Aspects of the Tooling API's data structures, much like the Metadata API, seem optional at first, but some it would appear not. My theory behind your error message is that you need to set some more information in the Metadata section, such as the field type, as it seems Salesforce is thinking your wanting to change it since your not passing it.

**Attempted Tooling API Approach**. To work around thus, i would typically advise retrieving the custom field first, then modify the data structure and perform the update. However in this case, no matter what i try it seems i get a mostly blank set of Metadata information back from my Tooling API SOQL query over CustomField. I'll see if i can get the Tooling API developer to comment here.

```
Select Id, Metadata, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix, TableEnumOrId 
 From CustomField 
 Where DeveloperName = 'YesNo'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do All the classes of the financial force needs to be imported in my org.

Comment: No only MetadataService.cls and MetadataServiceTest.cls.

Comment: Hi Andy, Came across this wierd issue

Comment: Save or update not supported in active organizations. i faced this in production.

Comment: Yeah i guess the API is for DE orgs is what they are trying to enforce by this perhaps? I still prefer the MD API for a lot of Setup related API work tbh and it works in Production. ;-)

Comment: Ok Thanks. I did try MD API wrapper provided by you. Its great. Just i was stuck at test class for adding value to picklist. can you provide a sample test class

Comment: Sure, there is one in the MetadataServiceExamples.cls.

Answer (score 0):

The above gievn solutions works using Apex Metadata Service (https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/); but it requires to import all code for even a small requirement. After, release of Tooling API, I find it lifesaver for such implementation without importing and managing too much code. We just need to make a callout using Tooling API.

Full detail article is here: https://sfdcian.com/update-picklist-value-and-add-it-in-record-type-using-apex-salesforce/

```
PATCH
/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N540000071QJG
Body: <as given at below URL>
```

Here is JSON Body that has to be sent as request body in this callout: https://github.com/ayub-ansari/Create-Picklist-Field-Using-Apex/blob/master/FirstHTTPRequestToUpdatePicklistField